# Как вывести переменные через определенное время?

Tags: php, ajax

У меня есть цикл, который должен выводить переменную каждые 2 секунды, 10 раз. Я попробовал вот так, но она выводит все сразу через 20 секунд. То есть она ждет пока действия выполнится 10 раз. А мне надо что бы если цикл один раз выполнился, то выводить один раз, а потом через две секунд  вывести второе значение.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i <10 ; $i++) { 
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo $_POST['number'];
    sleep(2);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Средствами PHP никак (хотя вот кеширование вывода, но тут, насколько я понимаю, не тот случай). Суть этого скриптового языка в том, что он сначала полностью выполняется, а после этого возвращает результат веб-серверу для передачи клиенту.

Для интерактива в окне браузера используйте JavaScript.